# Mysql select on a table

Tags: mysql, select

I have a mysql table with following columns:

Id1, id2, timestamp

The id2 is an auto increment entry. The id2 is not unique. so you may have a following rows:

1,12, 983475
2,12, 092348
3,23, 987455
4,23, 908457

I need to get following rows where the timestamp is the latest on the id2.

ie the results will be:

1,12,983475
3,23,987455

Also, the numbers 987455 and 983475 are just fictitious...

Help please...

Comment: Helpful article: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery with the `max()` aggregate for this:

```
select y.id1, y.id2, y.timestamp
from yourtable y
   join (select id2, max(timestamp) maxtimestamp
         from yourtable
         group by id2
    ) y2 on y.id2 = y2.id2 and y.timestamp = y2.maxtimestamp
```

This could possibly return ties -- if you truly want a single row per distinct `id2`, then you can use `user-defined variables` to establish a row number.

Comment: Thank you for the direction.. Will test and see how I go.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT id2 FROM table ORDER BY max(timestamp) DESC LIMIT 0, 1

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this won't work as it will only return one row.

So the table structure could be :

1,12, 983475 
2,12, 092348 
3,23, 987455 
4,23, 908457

And the answer has to be :
1,12, 983475 <br>
and<br>
3,23, 987455<br>

Comment: SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY timestamp DESC

Answer (score 0):

Select and restrict using max(timestamp)

e.g. select * from table where timestamp=(select max(timestamp) from table

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this won't work as it will only return one row.